# Will ansible crash if I removed the /etc/ansible directory?

Tags: ansible

I only see few files in /etc/ansible directory.

1. ansible.cfg
2. hosts
3. roles directory

My question is, will there be costly consequences if I removed the /etc/ansible directory all together and started creating my own ansible project directories?

Comment: why you want to delete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*Will ansible crash if I remove the /etc/ansible directory?*"**

A: No. Ansible will not crash if you remove /etc/ansible directory, or, in some systems, /usr/local/etc/ansible directory. The configuration default values are "hardcoded". See

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump
```

Provide your path to the inventory if you remove the *hosts* file. For example

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_HOST_LIST
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/scratch/tmp/ansible.cfg) = ['/scratch/tmp/hosts']
```

Provide your path to the roles too if needed. For example

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH
DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH(/scratch/tmp/ansible.cfg) = ['/scratch/tmp/roles']
```

See [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings).